# ng-if is not working inside nested ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I have nested the ligne_commandes under the commandes using ng-repeat to get only the command lines of every command and I used ng-if to verify this. My problem is that I'm getting all the command line . Here is my code:

```
<td ng-repeat="commande in vm.commandes track by commande.id">
   <tr ng-repeat="ligne_commande in vm.ligne_commandes track by ligne_commande.id">
   <div ng-if="ligne_commande.commande_id == commande.id ">
   <td>  {{ligne_commande.id}} </td> </div>
   </tr>
</td>
```

Any suggestion would be appreciated

Comment: You've got an invalid HTML structure: `<td>` can only have `<tr>` as a parent element, and `<tr>` must have either `<table>`, `<thead>`, `<tbody>` or `<tfoot>` as a parent element. This is likely to be messing up your output.

Comment: What do you mean by "My problem is that I'm getting all the command line"?

Comment: @caroline can you add a fiddle/plnkr with dummy data?

Comment: @Anfelipe I want to get just the line comande of the commande in vm.command , but using this code I'm getting all the command lines

Comment: @KhalidHussain sorry but I didn't understand you :(

Comment: If I replace commande.id in  **<div ng-if="ligne_commande.commande_id == commande.id ">**   with      **<div ng-if="ligne_commande.commande_id == ' ' ">**  I don't get any line so the problem seem that commande_id is not getted I don't know why

Comment: @Caroline https://plnkr.co/ and the like are web tools to debug code directly in your browser, you could provide more context and some samples of your data so we can understand better what you need.
Without knowing anything about the nature or structure of your data is very hard to guess, and also, do you have to use that horrible markup? (sorry but it's just too noisy).